# In visual studio 2008, how do I create different debug/release profiles?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

We have three servers for each mode:

1. Development
2. Testing
3. Production

Each one of them has different settings for connecting to the database, different base paths for resource accessing etc.
How do I create different debug and release modes for each of those server types and how do I force them to use a different configuration file?
Is there an easy way to switch between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on project->properties->Configuration Manager.

To create solution profile("configuration"):
Click drop-down "Active Solution profiles", select edit.

To create project profile("configuration"):
In "project contexts" "grid", click on dropdown from "Configuration" column, select edit.

To select project profile for solution profile:
Select active solution configuration, then select desired project configurations for each project.

Each profile can have different settings - i.e. target path, include directories, etc, etc - basically everything you can set on property pages can be different for each profile.
They will use same file though.

Comment: What do you mean they will use the same file?

Comment: @the_drow: I.e. project will always have same set of files (*.h, *.cpp, *.rc, etc) regardless of current profile - you can't add a file for a "debug" profile only. You still will be able to individually exclude files from build for every project profile, but they all will be listed in Solution Explorer.